# onclick open new tab casperjs

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

I've been confuse for this one week to solve this `onClick`.
I have some case for capturing this page form one site for tracking cargo.

this is the page when I open that link : 
[image]

That "More History" is a hyperlink using `onClick` contains _blank. when I click that, it will bring to new tab. And the page that I want to scrap using casperjs is in the new tab. 
I can scrap for the first container, but after that, I can't back to main page for clicking another container history for getting another page

this is my code :

```
casper.start('http://www.wanhai.com/views/Main.xhtml');

casper.waitForSelector(x('//form[@id="cargoTrackListBean"]'), 
    function success() {

        this.then(function() {
            this.sendKeys(x("//input[@id='q_ref_no1']"), BL_number, {keepFocus: true}); 
        }); 

        this.thenClick(x('//input[@value="Query"]'));

        this.wait(5000, function() {
            this.then(function() {
                links = this.evaluate(function () { 
                    var elements = __utils__.getElementsByXPath('//a[contains(text(), "More History")]'); 
                    return [].map.call(elements, function(element) {
                        // return element.children[0].innerText.trim();
                        return element.getAttribute("onclick");
                    });
                });

                // this.echo("onclick :"); 
                // this.echo(JSON.stringify(links));

                var i = 2;

                this.each(links,function(self,Container){
                    this.wait(10000, function() {
                        this.then(function() {
                            this.echo(i);
                            this.thenClick(x('//a[@onclick="'+Container+'"]'));

                            this.then(function() {
                                this.waitForPopup(/CargoTrackHistory\.xhtml/g,  
                                function success() { 
                                    this.echo("popup");
                                    this.withPopup(/CargoTrackHistory\.xhtml/g, function() {
                                        this.wait(7000, function() {

                                            this.capture(fs.workingDirectory.concat('/result/wanhai_').concat(i).concat('_look.png')); 
                                            this.then(function() {
                                                this.thenClick(x('//a[contains(text(), "[Close Page]")]'));

                                                this.then(function() {
                                                    i = i + 1;
                                                });                                                 

                                            }); 
                                        });
                                    });
                                }, function fail() { 
                                    this.echo("Gagal Popup");  
                                    this.capture(fs.workingDirectory.concat('/result/wanhai_').concat(i).concat('_broken.png'));
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });

                this.then(function() {
                    self.close();
                }); 

            }); 
        });
    }, 
    function fail() {
        fs.write(fs.workingDirectory.concat('/result/wanhai_').concat(BL_number).concat('_error.html'), this.getHTML() , 'w');  
        this.capture(fs.workingDirectory.concat('/result/wanhai_').concat(BL_number).concat('_error.png'));             
        this.echo ("Error!: Parsing HTML#input\n".concat(this.getHTML())).exit();
        this.echo('gagal');
    }); 

casper.then(function() {
    this.echo("Success !");
    // this.echo(result);
    this.exit();
});

casper.run();
```

can anyone give me some advice, thank you:)

Comment: You have a `self.close();` in you code, so you probably should remove that.

Comment: thank you @ArtjomB. I've tried for remove `self.close();` but still same.